# Ways one can select 6 pieces of fruit from a bowl.

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways can we select 6 pieces of fruit from a bowl, containing apples, oranges, and pears? If repetition allowed and there are at least 4 pieces of each type of fruit in the bowl.

**My Thinking**

I create some notation for simplicity. Let (a,b,c) denote that a apples,b oranges, and c pears are chosen.
where $a+b+c=6$ and each of a,b,c can vary from 0 to 4.
[as there are **at least** 4 fruits of each type, so we do not know there are 5 apples/oranges/pears in the bowl or not. Hence 'a' or 'b' or 'c' cannot take the value 5]

1. (4,2,0). Now these 3 numbers can permute amongst themselves. Hence we get $3!$ ways of picking 6 fruits in the above type.
   Similarly, I write the other types below.
2. (4,1,1). As 2 numbers are the same. Number of ways: $\frac{3!}{2}=3$.
3. (3,3,0). Number of ways: $3$.
4. (3,2,1). Number of ways: $3!$.
5. (2,2,2). Number of ways: $1$.

So the total number of ways to select 6 pieces of fruits are $2.3!+2.3+1=19$.

Am I correct? Or am I missing out something?

Comment: How many fruits are there in the basket and any restrictions on $6$ fruits that you have to fetch?

Comment: There is no restriction on the number of fruits in the basket.

Comment: Just so you understand the question does not make sense. "at least" provides no upper bound on what to select from.

Comment: If there were at most four fruits of each type in the bowl, you could subtract those cases in which more than four fruits of one type were selected from the total number of cases.  However, in your problem, there is not enough information to determine which cases must be excluded.